# Wordpress Install@VPS :: Folder permissions, FTP & Openpanel

Tags: permissions, ftp, vps, wordpress

I use openpanel with my vps and i am currently working on a plain wordpress install. When i create a new vhost the permissions of the folder are set to the owner 1001(root) thus i cannot really make normal edits to the configuration file(wp-config.php) and save them. Am i doing something wrong?
As ftp user i use the credentials of the user i created after the installation of openpanel. What's the difference between the initial user, the master ftp and the website ftp user?
I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After logging in to Openpanel with your openpanel-admin user, click on the User tab and in the bottom left corner, click the + symbol to create a new user (for example "user"). Just fill out the form and select openpanel-admin as the owner.

Then go to the Domain tab, create a new Domain (eg. "domain.com"), and set the user you just created as the owner. Select the newly created domain in the panel’s side bar and click 'Setup DNS Master'. Fill in the domain name and hit Create.

Under Domain, click on the Website tab. Click "Setup Virtual Host". Fill out the domain name (optionally enter the site admin email address) and hit Create.
Under Domain, click on the FTP Account tab and then "Set Up FTP Account". The username must be in the format, "user@domain.com".

Proceed with 'Set Up Email', 'Set Up Mailbox', Database and MySQL user like usual.
When you're finished SSH on to your server, go to your /home directory, and apply the following commands to your domain directory.

```
sudo chown -R [username]:www-data /home/[username]
sudo chmod -R g+s /home/[username]
sudo echo 137 027 > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Umask
sudo /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
```

Now you'll be able to upload files with your new FTP user, to your username's home directory with the appropriate permissions and the ability to make them writable for Apache.
Here's a forum post from the openpanel forums regarding a similar case: http://forum.openpanel.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=439